How can get a list of installed codecs and supported sound/media file types using powershell?
Since I have no idea how to do this, I have no code of my own. I asked Copilot, which provided the following as a "solution", but that doesn't work. It just gives me
Get-CimInstance: Invalid query. I suspect that the code it provided is for older windows versions.
# Get the list of installed video codecs 
$videoCodecs = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_VideoCodec -Filter "Group = 'video'"
$videoCodecs | Select-Object Name, Version

# Get the list of installed audio codecs
$audioCodecs = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_AudioCodec -Filter "Group = 'audio'"
$audioCodecs | Select-Object Name, Version

# Get the list of supported file types
$mediaTypes = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_MediaFileTypes $mediaTypes | Select-Object FileDescription, FileType

How can I get this to work on Win-11 ?

UPDATE:
None of the CIM Classes above are available in Windows-11.
It seem that any codecs (and info of) are embedded in some DLL's.
# Get-CimInstance Win32_CodecFile | Select Version, Name | Sort -Property Name

Version         Name
-------         ----
10.0.22621.2506 C:\Windows\system32\IMAADP32.ACM
10.0.22621.1    C:\Windows\system32\IYUV_32.DLL
1.9.0.401       C:\Windows\system32\L3CODECA.ACM
10.0.22621.2506 C:\Windows\system32\MSADP32.ACM
10.0.22621.2506 C:\Windows\system32\MSG711.ACM
10.0.22621.2506 C:\Windows\system32\MSGSM32.ACM
10.0.22621.2506 C:\Windows\system32\MSRLE32.DLL
10.0.22621.2506 C:\Windows\system32\MSVIDC32.DLL
10.0.22621.1    C:\Windows\system32\MSYUV.DLL
10.0.22621.1    C:\Windows\system32\TSBYUV.DLL

# ffind 'C:\Windows\System32' '*codec*.dll'

C:\Windows\System32\IconCodecService.dll
C:\Windows\System32\mibincodec.dll
C:\Windows\System32\mimofcodec.dll
C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d_codecvt_ids.dll
C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140_codecvt_ids.dll
C:\Windows\System32\rtmcodecs.dll
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCodecs.dll        # <--- Interesting!
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCodecsExt.dll     # <--- Interesting!
C:\Windows\System32\wmcodecdspps.dll
C:\Windows\System32\Microsoft-Edge-WebView\msvcp140_codecvt_ids.dll

Note that, in the 1st list of files:

Audio codecs are embedded in the ACM files.
Video codecs are embedded in the DLL files.

So I don't know how to simply extract info from those.

From a YT video, apparently you can find the Codecs by clicking on a well hidden link in the deprecated Windows Media Player. I don't have that and I don't think it comes with Win-11 (?). But clicking on that link, it generates a the wmpsupport.htm web file in your C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp, and it looks like this:

Second option that also shows all codecs is the Nirsoft tool called InstalledCodec.
I doubt it is going through all DLL's to extract all the codecs, so probably it is scanning the Registry.
I just read the description of that program, and they say:

InstalledCodec extract the information from 2 places in the Registry:
The Codec drivers list is loaded from:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32
The DirectShow filters list is loaded from:
HKCR\CLSID\{083863F1-70DE-11d0-BD40-00A0C911CE86}\Instance

Let's have a look.
Yep there they are. In the DS keys, for each CLSID folder you can find under FriendlyName is the descriptive name of the decoder.
Not sure of any reason why MS decided to keep this so difficult to find?
Is there a more simple way?

Get-CimInstance Win32_CodecFile is probably what you're looking for

As an aside: None of the CIM/WMI classes used in your code seem to exist on my W11 machine (at least not in the default namespace).

Problem with Win32_CodecFile is that it only seem to provide the name of the DLL or ACM file, nothing else.
